# What is the best way to Import a SQL file into the created DB in elastic beanstalk

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have SQL file and I want to import it to MySQL in beanstalk
what is the best solution to that?
waiting to spin up ec2 and then inject it from there?

Answer (score 1):

Usually something like that would be done in [container_commands](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/customize-containers-ec2.html#linux-container-commands).

The reason is that this is the only section in `.ebextentions` which supports `leader_only` option:

> Only run the command on a **single instance** chosen by Elastic Beanstalk. Leader-only container commands are run before other container commands. A command can be leader-only or have a test, but not both (leader_only takes precedence).

This means that if your EB has several instances in load-balanced env type, the `container_commands` with `leader_only` would **execute only on one of them**. This off course makes sense when you bootstrap your database, as you would want to run such logic only once during deployment.